# How to disable onBackPressed() for AlertDialog flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've got an `AlertDialog()` that it's `barrierDismissible` has been set to `false`. But yet when user presses the back button on android device the AlertDialog closes. How can I compeletly prevent the user from closing the AlertDialog()?

Here's what I've done so far:

```
          return showDialog<bool>(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: false,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Title'),
                content: Text('This is the alert dialog content'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('ok'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      print('ok you win');
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this way use [**`WillPopScope()`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) to handle `onBackPressed()` event

```
showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            barrierDismissible: false,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return WillPopScope(
                                onWillPop: () {return Future.value(false);},
                                child:  return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Title'),
                content: Text('This is the alert dialog content'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('ok'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      print('ok you win');
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
                              );
                            });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the WillPopScope as a parent of the AlertDialog

```
  showDialog(context: context,builder: (BuildContext context)
          {
              return WillPopScope(
                onWillPop: () async =>false,
                              child: AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Title'),
                  content: Text('Sample'),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('ok'),
                      onPressed: (){
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
```

Comment: no it's not about pressing back button on the page to show a alert dialog. I want to prevent the user from Closing the AlertDialog. am I clear?